# docker out of memory

Tags: docker, out-of-memory

I'm new to docker and have a problem with existing scripts that work on one machine but not on another. I'm willing to read documentation and existing answers but am a little lost on the many levels of abstraction in this topic.

Running an application in docker results in an out of memory exception.  I start docker with `--ulimit memlock -1:-1` and no other limit on memory seems to be applied.

`df -h` inside docker yields

```
root@localhost:/# df -h
Filesystem                                                                                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/docker-253:0-1312128-9219e5dbff0bc6da3a663fab31ec34e6f6b28ba6c8fbd3b343d9131d41f6b1c9   10G  3.0G  7.1G  30% /
tmpfs                                                                                              3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                                                              3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/fedora-root                                                                             50G   20G   28G  42% /etc/hosts
/dev/mapper/fedora-home                                                                            401G  151G  231G  40% /var/results
shm                                                                                                 64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
```

When the OOM occurs, the first file system is used to 95%.  Where does this limit 10G come from? Where could I adjust it?

All partitions of my device surely have enough free space.

```
[uscholz@localhost RegressionTesting]$ docker info
Containers: 2
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 52
Server Version: 1.10.3
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-253:0-1312128-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 12.17 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 32.16 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 7.889 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.14 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Either use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` or use `--storage-opt dm.no_warn_on_loop_devices=true` to suppress this warning.
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.122 (2016-04-09)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: journald
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge null host
Kernel Version: 4.8.12-200.fc24.x86_64
Operating System: Fedora 24 (Twenty Four)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
Number of Docker Hooks: 2
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 7.787 GiB
Name: localhost.localdomain
ID: YXHN:34PG:ZQA3:P4DU:4TFY:6THC:VFI2:E7BE:IGOW:2TTH:3BS7:3OOD
Registries: docker.io (secure)
```

Comment: why are you running `df` inside a docker container when the error is OOM? The two are basically unrelated

Comment: The application running inside the container gives an OOM. So I suspect the container reaching its limit

Comment: Do you mean "memory" or "disk space"?

Answer (score 0):

> Where does this limit 10G come from?

It comes from dockerd (daemon) which create special 'device' 10G size by default for new container

> Where could I adjust it?

You can set it by providing `--storage-opt dm.basesize=50G` to dockerd is case of devicemapper storage driver

**P.S.: actually, OOM not cause of disk space, but memory, i think**
And there are two possible reasons:

- you out of real memory. Than use `free -m` on docker host machine to watch it. Container use the same memory as host with docker
- you out of shared memory. Not sure about OOM, but docker set /dev/shm to  64M by default. It is not appropriate for some applications